# I was wondering if someone could teach me how to use cookies in my code

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a "Window.alert game" in a browser window for fun, but I can't figure out how to use cookies to save player data if they mess up or close the window. Can someone help me?

Comment: You can use cookies or `localStorage.getItem()` and `localStorage.setItem()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage since you can only save strings you will want to make them json objects and save them as strings and parse them when getting them

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage is indeed your best option for saving data semi-permanently. One thing to remember is that localStorage only supports strings, so if you need to store more complex objects, you should JSON.stringify them (and JSON.parse the result when loading data).

A simple pattern is to use a single object to store your state, and to save this state to localStorage whenever a change is made to it (so that your latest data is always persisted). You can also listen to the window.beforeUnload method to save your state right before the window closes, but this may not always work (eg: if your browser or tab closes unexpectedly).

Here is an example of what you can do:

```
// saves your state to localStorage
function save(state) {
    localStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(state));
}

// execute code when the document is loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    // load your state from localStorage if it has been previously saved
    // otherwise, set the state to an empty object
    var state = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('state')) || {};


    // show your name if previously saved
    // otherwise, prompt for a name and save it
    if (state.name) {
        alert('Your name is: ' + state.name);
    } else {
        state.name = prompt('What is your name?');
        save(state);
    }
});
```

To clear localStorage, you can call `localStorage.clear()`.